# What is a "glide rotation" really called?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

There are many webpages explaining what *glide reflections* are, see, e.g., 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_reflection
It is defined as a reflection followed by a translation.

My question is: What do you call a rotation (linear, i.e., around the origin) followed by a translation? 
Could be called a "glide rotation" but this gives very few hits. What is the proper terminology?

Any comments would be appreciated!

**Edited** My rotation is linear!

Comment: "What do you call a rotation followed by a translation? " I call it a *rotation*.

Comment: If the rotation is not the identity then a glide rotation is itself a rotation.

Comment: @AnginaSeng My rotation is assume to be linear.

Comment: There are nonlinear rotations?!

Comment: There’s no standard term that I know of. As @WimC points out, a rotation composed with a translation (in either order) is just a rotation about some point other than the origin.